# android return activity extras returns null

Tags: android

When trying to pass data from one activity to another it works fine in one direction parent>>child. But the return path child>>parent crashes I think with a null pointer exception.
Now I can trap the null easy enough but cant figure out where my passed int is getting lost?

How do you debug this type of problem – any insight etc…

the crash occurs of the line: int binVal = extras.getInt("binVal");

```
// when leaving the child activity
OnClickListener mReturnListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.putExtra("binVal", (int)binVal);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
};  



//on return to the parent actvity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) { 
    case SET_BIN_TEMP:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {           
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras == null)
                Toast.makeText(PilotActivity.this, "null returned!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                 int binVal = extras.getInt("binVal");
                 text.setText(Integer.toString(binVal));
             }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at your `onActivityResult(...)` parameters...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

When an Activity that has been started with `startActivityForResult` returns, the `Intent` returned is the parameter `data`.

In your 'parent' Activity you are using its `getIntent()` method which returns the `Intent` (if any) which started the Activity originally.

Instead of...

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

...you should use...

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
```

Comment: Outstanding and thank you for the insight. Changing to data.getExtras() solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with this in the past and had to do something like the code sample below:

```
OnClickListener mReturnListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.putExtra("binVal", (int)binVal);

        if (getParent() == null)
            YourActivity.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        else
            YourActivity.this.getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();
    }
};
```