# Android Challenge: skipped frames... shutdown VM... NULLPointerException.. on return of Intent data to onActivityResult

Tags: android-intent, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I've got a bit of a challenge... Here is the following high level:

### From a user perspective:

they get an activity (StockCountListActivity) that shows them a list of open stock counts
- they choose one and go to another activity (StockCountActivity) that shows them all the items they can then update qtys on.

### Behind the scenes:

the data for both those activities comes from a web service... I've written the following class as a helper:

```java
public class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
```

with the customary async methods... it does its magic no problem... and in the end calls

```java
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     resultString = result;
    _listener.handleResponse(taskNumber,scode,result);
    pDlg.dismiss();

}
```

where the _listener is actually an interface I've written as a hook to go back to the calling class (either Activity)... as per the following:

```java
public interface WebTaskListener {
    public void handleResponse(int tasknum, int scode, String result);
}
private WebTaskListener _listener;
```

All of this works great so far... Now comes the challenge...  in the handleResponse of the child activity (StockCountActivity) I have the following:

```java
@Override
public void handleResponse(int tasknum, int scode, String result) {
    if (result == null)
        return;
    if (tasknum == PUTCOUNTITEMS_TASK)
    {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("selGroup",-1);
        returnIntent.putExtra("selChild",-1);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
        this.finish();
    }

}
```

Through debugging I can verify that the returnIntent is correct here and the extras have been added correctly with the -1 values...  My intention(no pun intended) here is to trickle up to the StockCountListActivity (the first user dialog) and pass up these values.  What actually happens is quite different...

First... as background... I originally called the StockCountActivity (second dialog) with the following code from StockCountListActivity (first dialog):

```java
    Intent startNewActivityOpen = new Intent(this, StockCountActivity.class);
    startNewActivityOpen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    int newCountID = addNewCount(n);
    startNewActivityOpen.putExtra("CategoryID", n);
    startNewActivityOpen.putExtra("LoadType", "new");
    startNewActivityOpen.putExtra("CountID", newCountID);
    startNewActivityOpen.putExtra("selGroup", -1);
    startNewActivityOpen.putExtra("selChild", -1);
    startActivityForResult(startNewActivityOpen, 1);
```

Finally... after this long winded explanation... the problem is on the onActivityResult in the StockCountListActivity.

```java
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && data != null) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    currentCount.selGroup = extras.getInt("selGroup", -1);
                    currentCount.selChild = extras.getInt("selChild", -1);
                }
```

The data has no extras and is empty even though I've verified it is fine leaving the StockCountActivity.  The logCat shows the following.

```java
    05-02 09:39:59.664: I/Choreographer(16548): Skipped 3206 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    05-02 09:44:30.304: D/AndroidRuntime(16548): Shutting down VM
    05-02 09:44:30.304: W/dalvikvm(16548): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c15930)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.oat/.StockCount.StockCountActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.oat/com.oat.StockCount.StockCountListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at com.oat.StockCount.StockCountListActivity.onActivityResult(StockCountListActivity.java:323)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
    05-02 09:44:30.374: E/AndroidRuntime(16548):    ... 11 more
```

To summarize, the sequence of events is as follows.
1) the WebServiceTask (an AsyncTask) completes its work and then
2) is calling back to the StockCountActivity's handleResponse method
3) which in turn is creating the returnIntent and finishing the activity
4) which is then going back to the StockCountListActivity's onActivityResult method

I believe real problem is the message telling me that there is too much happening on the main thread and then it shutting down the VM. once that happens, I can understand why the Intent data gets lost. I just have no idea why it is complaining that I am doing too much work on the main thread.

I'm sure I am doing something stupid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... after many many hours of debugging and research... came across a great answer at the following:

[android return activity extras returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224559/android-return-activity-extras-returns-null)

it seems as though the real issue here was at this following line:

```
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

it should be:

```
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
```